# Style column-span seems not to work in tables

Tags: html, css, css-tables, css-multicolumn-layout

I want to avoid using `colspan` and rather go for CSS. In [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-span) it's suggested that I can use `column-span`. It's well-documented in many blogs etc.

However, entering it to my code, renders the `td` over one column only.

I also get a weird error message that e.g. 4 isn't a valid value for that style. I tried using `all`, which removed the warning but still didn't render as required.

I suspect that I'm missing something. Am I?

Comment: @Ren What code? It's `<td style='column-span: all;'>x</td>` more or less. The actual markup is a bit more extensive but removing the extras, I still get the same behavior.

Comment: @Ren Actually, the question is so simple that the code provided doesn't really give any more info. As for the people on this site, you might want to gain a bit more rep before speaking for the community as a whole. In fact, people on this site frown upon asking for code sample when a user can't answer a question just to hide own ignorance. Not saying this is so with your comment but I'm saying that it **might** be the case. And I hardly see the point of asking for any more info as the stated code (which you approved) was implied already. Would you agree?

Comment: @Ren IE, Cr and FF. Same behavior...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `column-span` property is not intended for use in tables, but in DIVs that have a `column-count` setting. See an example here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_column-span

Therefore it won't work in tables, also not in DIVs with table properties.